# Understanding about continuity of partials in multivariate calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

For $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, if all of the partials of f is continuous at $\vec a$, does that mean that they also exist around $\vec a$?

Motivated by the Theorem for differentiability at a point $\vec a \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

If the partials are continuous at $f(\vec a) : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and exist around $\vec a$, then $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$.

Basically, to deduce that a certain function is differentiable at some point $\vec a$, is it sufficient to simply check that all the partial derivatives are continuous at $\vec a$? Else, how am I supposed to even check that they "exist around $\vec a$".

Answer (score 0):

If you are given a function $f:  I \subset \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $a \in I$ then the partial derivative of $f$ at $a = (a_1,a_2)$ is defined as a limit :

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a) := \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(a_1+h,a_2)- f(a)}{h}.$$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a) := \lim_{h \to 0 } \frac{f(a_1,a_2 + h)- f(a)}{h}.$$

These respective limits may not exist and in such cases we say that the respective partial derivatives do not exist. If both limits exist then we say that the partial derivatives exist at $a$.

For a function $f$ to be differentiable at $a$ it is necessary that the partial derivatives exist at $a$. However it can happen that both limits exist but that the function $f$ is still not differentiable.

The theorem you have states that if these limits exist and that they are continuous as functions of $a$ then the function $f$ is differentiable.

Example : Consider

$$ f(x,y) = \vert x\vert.$$

We have
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y)= 
\begin{cases} 
1 & x > 0 \\
-1 & x < 0 \\
\not \exists & x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y)=  0
$$

These functions are both continuous at $(x,y)$ whenever $x \neq 0$. Hence $f$ is differentiable for all $(x,y)$ where $x \neq 0$. Moreover $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$ since the partial derivatives do not (all) exist at those points.